# How to pass a control as a parameter to delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, code-behind

I am needing to style a ComboBoxItem for a ComboBox that is being created in code behind. Here's my code so far

```
ComboBox cbo1 = new ComboBox();                
cbo1.IsTextSearchEnabled = true;
cbo1.IsEditable = true;

grid1.Children.Add(cbo1); 

cbo1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new StyleComboBoxItemDelegate(ref StyleComboBoxItem(cbo1), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);

public delegate void StyleComboBoxItemDelegate(ComboBox cbo_tostyle);

public void StyleComboBoxItem(ComboBox cbo_tostyle)
{
//code to style the comboboxitem;
}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
1. A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
2. Method name expected
```

Please can someone help me in pointing as to what I am doing  wrong?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either of these:

```
cbo1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(() => StyleComboBoxItem(cbo1)), 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);

cbo1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(() =>
    {
        //code to style the comboboxitem;
    }),
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Answer (score 1):

`StyleComboBoxItem()` "returns" void, so by using `ref StyleComboBoxItem(...)` you're actually trying to create a reference to void.

You could either:

- style the ComboBox on a separate line, and then supply the styled ComboBox to the delegate
- let `StyleComboBoxItem()` return the ComboBox it styled, so you can still use it inline

The ref is not needed.

Comment: The `ref StyleComboBoxItem(...)` relates to the delegate, not the method.